# @Consumes JSON in REST webservices with different number of JSON values each time

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I want to `@Consumes` a REST webservices with JSON type but the JSON input holds different number of values each time for example

```
{"name":"x","age":23,"language":"java"}
```

or

```
{"name":"c","age":"34","language":"c++","db":"oracle"}
```

So the input JSON may vary each time. How can I consume this type of JSON in my REST code?

Comment: Are you using Java and JAX-RS?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/, especially the section 'Working with JSON".

Comment: yes i am using Java and JAX-RS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Jersey and the JSON consumed may contain arbitrary key-value pairs, you could try something like this in your Jersey Controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/json-map")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeSortOfResponse receiveArbitraryJsonMap(Map<String,String> map) {
    // do stuff with map of key-value pairs
}
```

Your JSON should unmarshal to a Map which you can then use.

Alternatively, if your JSON resembles an arbitrary list a strings:

```
@POST
@Path("/json-list")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeSortOfResponse receiveArbitraryJsonList(List<String> list) {
    // do stuff with list
}
```

You will need to give the two endpoints different @Paths

Comment: thats working fine. can you tell me if my json input is like {"name","age","id","sex"} means i am receiving only key as json input can i use List<String> instead of map object (i tried it but its giving 400 error)

Comment: I have edited my answer addressing the submission of an arbitrary list of strings

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you will need a class mirroring the possible contents of your JSON.

For example:

```
public class Developer {

    private String name, language, db;

    private int age;

    // getters and setters

}
```

If your business logic allows for more than one language and database, you could include

```
private Set<String> language, db;
```

instead of the String fields.

Comment: actually its not about only language but my input  json will hold properties of different Pojo also say for example , name and language are from Developer pojo and age ,sex are from personal details pojo . this is example case only .

Comment: Yes - it will. In your first example, the field 'db' will simply be null.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer like below:

```
public Response jsonREST(InputStream incomingData) {

   StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   try {
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
       String line = null;
       while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println("output "+line);

           jsonBuilder.append(line);
       }
   } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
   }
   System.out.println("Data Received: " + jsonBuilder.toString());

   return Response.status(200).entity(jsonBuilder.toString()).build();
}
```

Thanks and what I need is I want to parse my json inside rest

Like I dont know the name of key so I want to parse the entire json and do some operation on it.

Comment: say for example i need to get the key value pair(in our case i want to get name,age,language,but i dont know what are the keys available inside the json ) and do some manipulation on it

Comment: Have you tried unmarshalling to a class with only a single field which is a Map<String,String>

Comment: How much control do you have regarding the JSON? Could the output look like this instead: "values" : {"name":"x","age":23,"language":"java"}

Comment: in my case i dont know the number of keys and their values and it can be any number

Comment: yes  my input json will be some times be like {"name":"x","age":23,"language":"java"} but someother times {"name":"x","age":23,"language":"java","sex":"female"}

Comment: and these key are from different pojo class may be from 10 different pojo classes

Comment: OK. It seems to me that you will not need to create a new Class for unmarshalling, as you are simply getting a JSON Map of arbitrary key-value-pairs. Could you please show the code of the REST method which receives the JSON?